# Can I crawl the html data in my Chrome browser using Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-chrome

My goal to control my Chrome web browser with Python program.
Especially I'd like to directly get html data of web page that i see.

Currently I'm using chrome extension + python program to resolve it.
See diagram of my [Current system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNatL.png).

chrome extension copies [document.documentElement.innerHTML] into clipboard,
python program retrieves the clipboard data and do some work(mouse click or keystroke).

I know the webbrowser module and urllib module in python.
However webbrowser module only open pages in my browser,
and urllib does not interact directly to my chrome browser.

Is there any method to get html data in my active chrome browser directly? like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGrK8.png)?

Comment: Have you tried searching google? http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

Comment: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html